# Rotate image clockwise and anti-clockwise in xaml for window store app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to rotate an image using c# for windows 8.1 app I tried in xaml

```
<Image Width="200" Height="50" Fill="Yellow" Source="a.png"/>          
    <!-- Rectangle with 45 degrees rotation -->
    <Image Width="200" Height="50" Fill="Blue" Opacity="0.5">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="0" Source="a.png" CenterY="0" Angle="45" />
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Image >
```

I am creating an image dynamically.Now I want to rotate that from same point clock wise and anti clock wise how i do that ?

Comment: Same thing, apply a render transform to it. Its going in an Image tag or other UIElement eventually, right? Perhaps I don't understand your question or what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes can you give some code here

Comment: I would be happy to, but I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide a bit more context/clarity?

Comment: I have a multiple image on canvas , now I want to rotate them I have a button

Comment: Now image click image opacity becomes 0.5 which make that it is selected now clicking rotate button will rotate that image.

Comment: Image imageToUse = new Image();                                             private void Tap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
            if (sender is Image)
            {

                var name = (Image)sender;
                if (name.Opacity == 1)
                {
                    name.Opacity = 0.5;
                    imageToUse =(Image) sender;
                }
                else if (name.Opacity == 0.5)
                {
                    name.Opacity = 1;
                }
              
            }

Comment: private void rotateObjects()
        {
            if (imageToUse != null)
            {
               
            RotateTransform rotateTransform1 = new RotateTransform();
              
            rotateTransform1.Angle = rotate;
                imageToUse.RenderTransform = rotateTransform1;
              
                rotate += 10;
            }

        }

Comment: So what is not working exactly?

Comment: image move to start of canvas not from the previous one and one error    Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.RotateTransform' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.TranslateTransform'.